# OpenGL Optimization or...?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm making a OpenGL game, and I have problem with optimization. When I start it, it does not respond. If in `Update()` I just put a `for` loop and `_time += 0.1f`, I get a blank screen.

```
void Update(){
    for(; ;){
        _time += 0.1f;
        Render();
    }
}

void Render() {
    glClearDepth(1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    _colorProgram.use();

    GLuint timeLocation = _colorProgram.getUniformLocation("time");
    glUniform1f(timeLocation, _time);

    _sprite.Render();

    _colorProgram.unuse();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::printf("OpenGL version is %s",glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    // Window
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(520, 200);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL [ Shader #1 error pt 3 ]");
    // Setup GLEW
    if( GLEW_OK != glewInit()){
        return 1;
    } while( GL_NO_ERROR != glGetError() );

    // After creating window
    Init();
    glutDisplayFunc(Render);
    Update();

   glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: GLUT has control of the main loop. You should not be infinite looping. Also `glGetError` only returns one error, so the while loop there is pointless.

Comment: IDK why this got marked down.  The existence of and need to think about a message pump isn't obvious to beginners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The infinite loop in `Update()` never lets GLUT pump the event queue.

Use `glutTimerFunc()` or `glutIdleFunc()` to call `Update()` instead.  That way execution flow periodically returns to GLUT and GLUT can do what it needs to keep the OS happy.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to run an animation with GLUT is to use a timer function. This way, GLUT can get back to its main loop, and call your display function. You're not supposed to call the display function directly from your own code.

For example, register a timer function during initialization (the first argument is a time in milliseconds):

```
glutTimerFunc(10, timerFunc, 0);
```

Then in the timer function:

```
void timerFunc(int value) {
    _time += 0.1f;
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(10, timerFunc, 0);
}
```

There are two critical pieces in the code fragment above:

- You do **not** call your `Render()` function directly. Instead, you call `glutPostRedisplay()` to tell GLUT that a redisplay is needed. It will then call your `Render()` function because you registered it as the display function with `glutDisplayFunc()`.
- You have to register the timer again. `glutTimerFunc()` fires the timer only once, not periodically. So you have to re-register it every time it fired.

There is one other problem in your code. You have these calls in your `main()`:

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
...
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);
```

The flags passed in the second call will override the ones from the first call. While `GL_RGBA` is the default anyway, you will not get a depth buffer because `GL_DEPTH` is missing in the second call. You can simply remove the second call, since the first one is most likely what you want.